# Running nextjs development mode with CSP and "style-src" with nonce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, content-security-policy

I'm not able to get nextjs development mode running with "style-src" CSP active. Currently i have only 2 errors left, but these impact my development flow:

[image]

I think this 2 errors would be the styling for error display in development mode and the refresh spinner.

is there a way to fix this (adding nonce or something). I want to have the same CSP for development as for production to not produce CSP errors after build. (ie. using inline style somewhere). If i have to use "unsafe-inline" for development i will not be notified until changes are build and deployed.

Using `__webpack_nonce__` also doesn't help.

Seams like the scripts try to inject a `<script>` element to the dom, but don't respect `__webpack_nonce__`. is there a way to force inject it to each element?

Comment: We now have official documentation for handling nonces and Content Security Policy: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

With just the error messages to work with I assume that the code is either inserting a style tag or a style attribute. Attributes are not nonceable and also will not work with hashes in many (or all) browser implementations. If it is a style tag it is likely that the module setting it doesn't support nonces. Try inserting the hash provided in the error message. If there are variations to the style you may have add multiple hashes. If you need to keep adding hashes for a long time, the hash route is not for you. If these hashes aren't needed in production they still do no harm, except require a tiny bit of bandwidth.

If you need to resort to 'unsafe-inline' in general, this isn't very bad for style-src if you restrict other parts of your CSP, according to https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Comment: the files added in the screenshot are from react and nextjs and they try to insert "<style>" tags. the problem is i don't know a way to override them to use nonces. is there a way to do so?

unsafe-inline for styles is still a security issue if you allow user input.

Comment: Clicking on the link in the error message will show you the code causing the violation. You should be able to see what kind of style is being inserted. You may also get an idea on whether the code supports inserting a nonce or not. Most likely it isn't.

Comment: yes, it isn't. im just asking if there is a way to force it, if the code not supports it. like injecting a nonce to the source code of third party files on webpack build.

Comment: I'm not aware of it. I have tried adding nonces on several occasions but generally fail as it the variable is cached and doesn't change between pageloads, or I'm not able to set the same nonce in the CSP and the tag, or it is just not possible to set the nonce in one place or the other. If the code is somewhat static I tend to end up with a hash, but if it is dynamic some other solution must be found.